# Test error : Status -> Expected: 422 Received: undefined

Tags: node.js, express, axios, jestjs

I am trying to test the following Typescript code:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { validate } from "./validator";
import pgp from "pg-promise";
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/checkout", async function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  const connection = pgp()("postgres://postgres:dev123@localhost:5432/tdd-app");
  try {
    const isValid = validate(req.body.cpf);
    if (!isValid) throw new Error("Invalid cpf");

    const output: Output = {
      total: 0,
    };
    const items: number[] = [];
    if (req.body.items) {
      for (const item of req.body.items) {
        if (item.quantity <= 0) throw new Error("Invalid quantity");
        if (items.includes(item.idProduct)) throw new Error("Duplicated item");
        const [productData] = await connection.query(
          "SELECT * FROM cccat10.product WHERE id_product = $1",
          item.idProduct
        );
        output.total += parseFloat(productData.price) * item.quantity;
        items.push(item.idProduct);
      }
    }

    if (req.body.coupon) {
      const [couponData] = await connection.query(
        "SELECT * FROM cccat10.coupon WHERE code = $1",
        [req.body.coupon]
      );
      if (couponData.expire_date.getTime() >= new Date().getTime()) {
        const percentage = parseFloat(couponData.percentage);
        output.total -= (output.total * percentage) / 100;
      }
    }
    res.json(output);
  } catch (e: any) {
    res.status(422).json({
      message: e.message,
    });
  } finally {
    await connection.$pool.end();
  }
});

type Output = {
  total: number;
  message?: string;
};

app.listen(3000);
```

And my test are this:

```
test("Shouldnt create an order with duplicated item", async function () {
  const input = {
    cpf: "684.053.160-00",
    items: [
      { idProduct: 1, quantity: 1 },
      { idProduct: 1, quantity: 1 },
    ],
  };
  const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/checkout", input);
  const output = response.data;
  expect(output.status).toBe(422);
  expect(output.message).toBe("Duplicated item");
});
```

When I put a console.log into the catch of the try catch code, you can confirm that the test is falling into the catch, but for some reason the status is not being sent, only the message.

If I remove the line

```
expect(output.status).toBe(422);
```

inside the test, it will be work.

The problem is with the output.status == undefined inside this specific test case.

I have other tests that can receive the status from the code:

```
 res.status(422).json({
  message: e.message,
});
```

like the test:

```
test("Shouldnt accept an order with an invalid cpf ", async function () {
  const input = {
    cpf: "406.302.170-27",
  };
  const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/checkout", input);
  const output = response.data;
  expect(response.status).toBe(422);
  expect(output.message).toBe("Invalid cpf");
});
```

Can someone help me to fix this status code on the test "Shouldn't create an order with duplicated item" ?

Comment: What makes you think the status should be in the data?

Comment: You aren’t setting the status in the json body

Comment: but why the other tests are returning the status code 422 from de try catch?

Comment: the second test that i show in the question is working very well and returning the status codes from the :

res.status(422).json({
  message: e.message,
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you're checking `output.status` and in the second example you're checking `response.status`. So try `response.status` in the first one.